# Random Algebra Problem

Tags: diophantine-equations, natural-numbers

Prove that if a, b, c, x, y, z, and $\alpha$ are natural numbers.
For every given set of x, y, z, the number $\alpha$ obtained from the following equation:

$$\frac{a^2}{x^2} + \frac{b^2}{y^2} + \frac{c^2}{z^2} = \alpha$$

cannot be obtained from other combination of a, b and c. In other words, every natural number $\alpha$ that satisfies the above equation can only be found from a unique set of a, b and c.

Comment: The second formulation seems wrong since if we take that $\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{x,y,z\}$ are solutions of this equation then so are $\{ma,mb,mc\}$ and $\{mx,my,mz\}$ where $m\in\mathbb{N}$
The first formulation if I understood correctly is that for $\{x,y,z\}$ exists only 1 set of $\{a,b,c\}$?Am I right?

Comment: x, y, z are fixed, you cannot choose mx, my, mz

Comment: only a, b, c change, thats why i say for every given set of x, y, z

Comment: Certainly for $x=y=z=1$, there are many integers $n$ that can be expressed in more than one way as a sum of three squares.

Comment: what happens when x,y,z are 3 distinct numbers?

Comment: Same thing, probably. I bet you could find examples, if you gave it a shot. Try something simple, like $x=1,y=2,z=3$. Multiply through by 36 to get $36a^2+9b^2+4c^2=n$. Take some moderately large $n$, like 1001, and see whether you can't find more than one solution.

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Any comments?

Comment: Yup, thanks a lot. Can you look at the second version of this question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743752/random-algebra-problem-2

Comment: The way to thank someone here is to "accept" the answer by clicking in the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $x$, $y$, $z$, let $a=Ax$, $b=By$, $c=Cz$; then the equation becomes $$A^2+B^2+C^2=n$$ There are many $n$ for which this equation has distinct sets of solutions $\{A,B,C\}$, for example, $$33=25+4+4=16+16+1$$ or $$38=36+1+1=25+9+4$$ or $$41=36+4+1=16+16+9$$ More examples at https://oeis.org/A223733